# Those Who Apply Knowledge vs Those Who Further Knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests

**I'm looking for two words.** They aren't opposites, but they sit on different ends of a spectrum.

---

### Word One

The first word describes someone who takes what they have learned and applies it in the 'real world'.

**Related to**: Creator, applier, worker

---

### Word Two

The second word describes someone who takes what they have learned and proposes new ideas in that field.

**Related to**: Theorist, innovator, researcher

---

It would be best if both of these terms were flattering, and of equal value.

Perhaps the 'related to's I've provided are the best available options; but someone with a greater lexicon will hopefully be able to provide a powerful pair of options.

Comment: Equal value?  Good luck with that.  Of course each side views itself as superior!

Comment: *engineer*, *scientist*

Comment: Inculcator; implementer ... developer, man of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Given the emphasis on equal value on not being judgmental, I'd go with *builder* for applied knowledge and *inventor* or *innovator* for innovation.   Neither term is too laudatory (*magnate*/*entrepreneur*), nor dismissive (*worker*/*tinkerer*).

The *builder* emphasizes that one can add value through doing work and applying perhaps non-innovative knowledge, while *inventor* or *innovator* emphasizes that there is some new idea in play that creates an advantage over existing players.  And in terms of not being too laudatory, we can all think of *builders* who did not become *magnates* and *inventors* who did not capitalize on their inventions at all.  Neither *builder* or *inventor* implies success.